# Look for string in output python?

Tags: python, youtube, google-api

Basically, I'm trying to make python check if a youtube channel is live by looking for a string in the response of the Google API. If the string is there, the channel is live, otherwise it is not.

My code right now is

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json, time, codecs, re
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=CHANNELID&type=video&eventType=live&key=KEY"
    response = urlopen(url)
    reader = codecs.getreader("utf-8")
    data = json.load(reader(response))
    print (data)
```

How could I add something to check if "'liveBroadcastContent': 'live" is in the response from that and set a value to true? Thanks.

Comment: You can pretty much do exactly what you described `if live in url: <do_action>`.

Comment: `'a_string' in 'another_string'` is how you check if a string is contained in another string.

Comment: It's a JSON though, not a string.

Comment: @Coldspeed Um. JSON *is a text based object serialization format*. If you are working with a JSON in your code, you are working with a string. Do you mean, it is a deserialized JSON, i.e. a Python object (some sort of list/dict combo)?

Comment: If it's JSON, `'key' in {dict}` still works, so you could do `'liveBroadcastContent' in data`

Comment: I think the right way to solve this problem is to observe the structure of the returned JSON. What else is there to do? I've worked with Google APIs before and they've excessively complicated structures but they follow the same format, so just study the structure and index.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah, meant that, sorry.

Comment: @Coldspeed I mean, it's certainly a pedantic point. But I think it is important. I see a lot of questions where the OP is equivocating between the JSON formatted string and the deserialized object, leading to much confusion.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah... people tend to use the terms JSON and JSON object interchangeably. That's a misnomer.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the pattern as you mentioned using regular expressions:

```
if 'livebroadcastcontent' in data:
    match=re.match(r'live', data)
    if match==true:
        print("its live")
```

Comment: Hi, I'm relatively new to python. I get this:
 match = re.match(r'live', data) if match==true:
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax